# Most efficient way to expand 2D array, with dimension (n x m) to a new array of dimension (n + w)(m + w), while keeping contents centered

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, realloc

I got an assigment for a set of programs that manipulate PPM image files. One of these programs consists of adding a colored frame of width *w* around the original image.

It wasn't very hard finding a solution, but I'm curious if it can be optimized as it doesn't seem the most elegant way to do it.

Im using an array `pixel **` (inside a `struct ppmfile` which also contains header data) to store the image data, it is allocated with this function:

```
pixel **imgdata(int xsize, int ysize)
{
    pixel **imgdata;
    
    imgdata = (pixel**)malloc(ysize*sizeof(pixel*));
  
    for(int i = 0; i < ysize; i++)
        (imgdata)[i] = (pixel*)malloc(xsize*sizeof(pixel));

    return imgdata;
}
```

This is the function I came up with:

```
void frame(ppmfile *ppm, int width, pixel color)
{  
    pixel **new_image = imgdata(ppm->xsize + (width*2), ppm->ysize + (width*2));

    //Copying to center of new pixel matrix

    for(int i = 0; i < ppm->ysize; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < ppm->xsize; j++)
            new_image[width + i][width + j] = ppm->imgdata[i][j];

    free_ppmimgdata(ppm);

    ppm->imgdata = new_image;
    ppm->xsize += width*2;
    ppm->ysize += width*2;

    //frame sides
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < ppm->xsize; j++)
        {   
            ppm->imgdata[i][j] = color;
            ppm->imgdata[ppm->ysize - i - 1][j] = color;
        }

    //frame top and bottom
    for(int i = width; i < ppm->ysize - width; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            ppm->imgdata[i][j] = color;
            ppm->imgdata[i][ppm->xsize - j - 1] = color;
        }
}
```

But this allocates an entirely new, bigger, array in memory while also having imo too many loops for something this simple... So my question is if it's possible to realloc() this type of matrix, while moving/copying/preserving its contents at the "center" of the new matrix - as (poorly) illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyzA6.png)? Are there any other ways you can see to optimize this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Jsut call `realloc` intead of `malloc` and remove the copy?

Comment: @KamilCuk: The new matrix has larger rows with new elements before the old data.

Comment: What is 'pixel'? 3 chars?

Comment: @tstanisl three ints R,G, B

Comment: Consider using char or uint8_t. It would reduce IO four times

Comment: Since the new layout requires the data in different positions, the data must be moved, and there is no way to avoid that. (If the difference between the old layouts and the new can be eliminated, as by allocating the enlarged space first and using the smaller array inside it until the additional space is needed, the data movement could be avoided.) However, there may be other efficiencies to be gained. The use of pointers-to-pointers to implement two-dimensional arrays is generally inefficient. A better method is arrays-of-arrays…

Comment: … The memory copying might be better done with one `memcpy` call per row instead of a loop, depending on compiler optimization and whether any of the various pointer dereferencing occurring in the loop interferes with optimization. Rewriting some of the other code to avoid use of pointers inside loops could allow improved optimization. Allocating the memory with consideration for cache characteristics could improve memory access. Rewriting the code to merge the loops where they access adjacent memory could help memory access…

Comment: … That is, instead of copying the interiors of each rows, then setting the new front and back frames of the rows, set the front of one row, then copy its interior, then set its back, and repeat for the next row. This uses memory consecutively, which is generally better for performance. These considerations are context-dependent, so the problem needs more analysis and description.